# LTspice IR2110 Nmosfet error simulation

Tags: ltspice

I got a task of building pure sine wave inverter, and I wanted to simulate my circuit before building it. File is in link. Problem is that the simulation stops after few seconds with error message:
I tried changing mosfet models, but it didn't help... Any ideas?

[image]

WRONG SCHEMATIC:
http://fifi.starkom.eu/rahchat/uploads/1593790276.asc

**EDIT:**

Solution was exactly right, thanks for fast help. There is working Schematic (looking a bit better, and also added deadtime)

NEW SCHEMATIC:
http://fifi.starkom.eu/rahchat/uploads/1593842342.asc

Comment: While it's nice that you shared your schematic, you are using 3rd party symbols and libraries, which not everyone would have. It's a [good idea](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/388544/95619) to copy these and the project in one folder, then archive it. This way, anyone downloading your archived project will get to have both your custom symbols and the libraries, models, etc.

Comment: I will update that, but I have all symbols mixed with those orginal ones..

Comment: Now that you got your answer, it might be too late (unless you consider future readers), but it's an advice that could prove useful to yourself, and to others, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for including the .asc file.

If you replace the IR2110 model with the IR2110A model it will converge, albeit rather slowly. I don't know the exact difference. [Others](http://valvol.ru/topic62-210.html) have had similar problems.

Comment: Thank You So MUCH! Worked Fine!!! PS.. What is unusual in sharing all resources that might be useful to solve the problem?

Comment: @fifi_22 Looking at your schematic (what is available to me, without having your custom symbols and libraries), are you sure you want to keep that particular configuration for the final half-bridge? If `R24` is meant to be the load, it will not function the way you'd expect it to. Also, all those wild connections make the schematic hard to read.

Comment: I know, the resistor is in the wrong place, but it wasnt ment to be load - I was trying to add some resistance in case that this could struggle simulator - I really tried strange things. Also schematic will be redrawn, i wanted to make sure everything is ready to make better one, and I will publish finished schematics, and if it will work - also board layouts etc.