# LTspice in macOS: issue with file path for new models

Tags: ltspice

All default symbols are in the "/Users//Library/Application Support/LTspice/lib/sym" folder.
So when I want to create a new symbol from a downloaded model,I save it in a separate folder I created within the "sym" folder.
However, when I try to use it in a schematic, it always shows "cannot find symbol" error.What works for me is when I save the schematic within the same folder where I have my symbol(folder within sym).
This seems to be a path issue and I'm not sure of how to resolve it.
Also, could you suggest a better method of saving new models because I feel adding folders within the default installation is probably not what is done generally.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388571/95619) helps? Did you close and reopened up LTspice after creating the symbol? I don't have MacOS, but is that path the default for the **installation**, or for the **user** files? E.g. is it in (the equivalent of) "Program Files", or "My Documents"? If the former then it will not work, it needs to be in the user's path. OTOH, MacOS version sometimes differs from the one from Windows, so it might be worth running the Windows one with Wine (or some emulator).

Comment: Yes the path mentioned is where the libraries are when LTspice is downloaded.