# LTspice: putting symbol files in "sub folders"

Tags: ltspice

[image]

I see the default LTspice symbols are in a structure of sub-folders.

When I press F2 for "Select Component Symbols" I can see these folders in brackets as [ADC], [Digital], etc.

How can I do the same thing in a new project's folder? I have so many symbols it's getting hard to scroll through.

I tried to setup a folder structure, but my subfolders do not show up in the "Select Component Symbol" window.

Answer (score 2):

The subfolders can only work in the default library path, which is in `%LocalAppData%\LTspiceXVII\lib\sym\`. If you want them to reside elsewhere, you can use the custom paths in the *Control Panel > Sym. & Lib. Search Paths*. Be sure to use both the symbols and the subcircuits (they can be duplicates because they're loading different things) if you want these last ones to be loaded automatically (e.g. without the need for `.lib` or `.inc`). You still won't get subfolders, but you can organize your 3rd party libraries and symbols to be in separate directories, something like this:

```
D:\Custom3rdPartySymsAndLibs\Analog\
D:\Custom3rdPartySymsAndLibs\Digital\
...
```

So you need a path for each directory, with all the directories inside a general folder (the *Custom3rdPartySymsAndLibs* from above), but then all of them will be visible in the *Top Directory* drop-down menu:

[image: topdir]

Comment: Note that I haven't said anything about using the `%LocalAppData%` folder (which can be used), mostly because of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388571/95619). It's not that you *can't* do it, it's that *if* you do it, *sharing* will become a *problem*.